# Implementing search feature sailsjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to build a simple search feature, but I can't figure out why my code is not working.

This is the action that I have built to search:

```
search: function(req, res) {

    var criteria = req.param('criteria');

    var value = req.param('value');


    Human.find().where({ criteria: value }).done(function(err, humans) {
      if(err) {
        return console.log('Error:' + err);
      }else{
        res.view({
          title: 'Search',
          humans: humans
        });
      }
    });
}
```

I have a button on my main page with the ID of search. I want to make it so that whenever someone clicks my search button, it queries the database and returns the results at localhost:1337/model/search. So far, I've tried sending an ajax request to that controller action with the two variables (criteria, value) but it doesn't work.

This is the ajax call that I am submitting:

```
$('#search').on('click', function() {
    var criteria = $('#filter').val();

    var value = $('#value').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/human/search',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            criteria: criteria,
            value: value
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('SUCCESS!');
            window.location.href = 'http://localhost:1337/human/search';
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('ERROR!');
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the corresponding view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th width="150">First Name</th>
    <th width="150">Last Name</th>
    <th width="150">Contact</th>
    <th width="150">E-Mail</th>
    <th>View</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<% _.each(humans, function(model) { %>
<tr>
<td> <%= model.id %> </td>
<td> <%= model.firstName %> </td>
<td> <%= model.lastName %> </td>
<td> <%= model.contact %> </td>
<td> <%= model.email %> </td>
<td><a href="/human/view/<%= model.id %>" class="tiny button">VIEW</a></td>
<td><a href="/human/edit/<%= model.id %>" class="tiny button">EDIT</a></td>
    </tr>
<% }) %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Promlem #1:** When you search the model like this: `Human.find().where({ criteria: value })`, you actually search by field named "criteria", instead of searching by field, which name is held in `criteria` variable.
Try to create search object like this:

```
var searchObj = {};
searchObj[criteria] = value;
// and then search like you did before
Human.find().where(searchObj).done(function(err, humans) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('Error:' + err);
    // you should return some response here:
    res.send(err, 500);
  }else{
    res.view({
      title: 'Search',
      humans: humans
    });
  }
});
```

**Problem #2:** why you do ajax request and then do redirect to the same url?
First, you make POST request, although GET request is more suitable for search pupposes. POST is usually used when you *create* resources.
Second, in ajax success handler, after you receive the view with found humans models, you just redirect browser to `http://localhost:1337/human/search` url **without** any parameters passed, so your controller will try to search by empty value and criteria `Human.find().where({ "": "" })`. So you'll not see expected result.

It's not clear whether you want to get data via ajax, or just to show it in new HTML page?

**EDIT:** If you don't want to use ajax, let the HTML form do the work for you:

```
  <form action="human/search">
      <input name="criteria" value="foo">
      <input name="value" value="bar">
      <button type="submit" id="search">Search</button>
  </form>
```

The search button click will submit the form and pass all form data in the GET request's query string: `http://localhost:1337/human/search?criteria=foo&value=bar`

Of course, you can build query string manually with javascript, without using form, and redirect browser to that url. Result will be the same.

Comment: Criteria => the property; Value => the value of that property; Basically, I was trying to write: Human.find().where({ id: 2} )(example: criteria = id; value = 2; )

Comment: I've tried the code that you provided and it still doesn't work. Maybe I'm missing something. I'll try to better explain the process. I have a button on the page with the ID of search (using Zurb Foundation Framework): <a id="search" href="/human/search" class="button">Search</a> When someone clicks this button, it fires up the on click event that I posted and navigates to localhost:1337/human/search; It returns an empty view;

Comment: Probably this is my main problem: How can I send data to a controller action without using ajax calls? Every time a user clicks on search I want the page to render the SEARCH view with the search results.

Comment: I apdated the answer with example without ajax

Comment: So, basically, whenever I call req.param() it searches for parameters within the URL, right? Up until now I was sending variables via ajax, without building up the URL.

Comment: req.param() search parameters within body of POST request, **OR** within query string(in case of GET request). This is the difference between these request types. GET request passes params in URL's query string, while POST request has params in it's body, not URL. req.param() function is smart and can get params from any type of request.

Comment: I've even tried that form that you posted, but it still doesn't work. Is there anyplace where we could chat, please?:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35837/discussion-between-ataman-and-shinpou)

Comment: As I understood from our discussion, my first answer was right:)